# trouble with wine on crouton

Tags: wine, crouton

I wanted to play half-life on my chromebook using crouton focal fossal,
it is unstable focal but i dont know if it has ties with my error.
I have installed wine using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

When i tried opening half life i got this:

```
(focal)nerd@localhost:~/Downloads/half/Half-Life/steamapps/common/Half-Life$ wine ./hl
wineserver: file_set_error() can't map error: Required key not available
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init failed to load L"M:\\home\\nerd\\Downloads\\half\\Half-
Life\\steamapps\\common\\Half-Life\\hl.exe", error c0000001
```

So how do i fix this?

Comment: You can't run software that isn't written for ARM in a ARM Chromebook, with or without Wine. Plus, Half-Life has a native Linux version (i386 or arm64 only). And knowing that the Steam client can't be installed in ARM and that the version you're trying to run is from Steam, the only possible conclusion is an attempt of piracy.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run x86_64 or x86 software such as Half Life on ARM processors, with OR without Wine - they don't speak the same language under the hood, and there's no way to really *make* them work on ARM infrastructure.

It simply will not work, and is not possible to get working because of the differences between x86 based systems and ARM processors - they don't speak the same language under the hood and the instruction sets simply don't exist or function for ARM processors.  You won't be able to run Windows software or Wine targeting x86 or x86_64 Windows applications because of the differences and incompatibility in the ARM architecture.

Comment: i have an amd chromeboo